Handling CORS Errors in Angular 19: Can SSR Resolve the Issue?
I’m using Angular 19 and encountering a CORS error when fetching data. I understand that the typical solution is to handle it on the backend, but I’m unable to do that at the moment. I was wondering if it's possible to resolve the CORS error using SSR (Server-Side Rendering).

Is this a feasible solution?
If so, how can I prevent the CORS error through SSR?
If not, what alternatives would you recommend for handling this issue?


CORS errors happen when the server doesn't allow the client to make requests. This is the default to protect other servers from being datamined. Remember, different ports also count as a different server, even if ip/hostname are the same. You have to set appropriate headers. Server-side rendering doesn't change the fact you are trying to get resources from a different site. See MDN docs - CORS

Keep everything same domain.  CORS errors come from the browser.  (It's the browser's way of keeping its users safe from cross-site attacks... usually theft of credentials)  The server can tell the browser what site(s) it allows to make cross-site requests, but no check will be made by the browser if you keep everything same-site.  If debugging locally (localhosts with different ports are treated as separate domains) you can use a profile with CORS rules turned off, or use a proxy to make front end back end run on same port.

Most people just add CORS headers to the backend, but this should only be done if you absolutely have to do that.  (and only for specific domains)  Adding those headers reduces your users' security.
